# Get instance of an mbean from a remote MBean Server

Tags: java, mbeans

I want to create a collector with java.
The collector must be able to collect informations of remote JVM using JMX.
It must be also capable of sending these informations to a user in JSON format thanks to a Restful Web service.
My question is:

- Can i get an instance of an MBean from a remote MBean server in order to convert it into JSON object and send it to user with a web service ?

*It possible to get any information of an MBean on a remote Mbean Server (attributes, values of attributes, operations ...) but i couldn't find a way to get an instace of an mbean.